# JS - data manipulation on array of objects with property that contains array

Tags: javascript

Example array -

```
    const arr = [
      {
        charge: [ { id: '1', qty: 10 }, { id: '2', qty: 20 } ],
        totalCharge: 100,
        qtySum: 50
      },
      {
        charge: [ { id: '3', qty: 30 }, { id: '4', qty: 40 } ],
        totalCharge: 70,
        qtySum: 100
      },
    ]
```

The math actions - (qty * totalCharge) / qtySum

Output (not real numbers) -

```
    [
      {
        id: '1',
        calcQty: 300,
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        calcQty: 250,
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        calcQty: 300
      },  
      {
        id: '4',
        calcQty: 400
      }
    ]
```

What I could not understand how to do is to separate the `charge` and only then do the math I need. Because I need to use the same `totalCharge` and `qtySum` each time based on how many organs are in the `charge` field, would love to get some help

Comment: Use nested loops.

Comment: The outer loop gets `totalCharge` and `qtySum`, the inner loop gets `qty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `map` and `flat`.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    charge: [
      { id: "1", qty: 10 },
      { id: "2", qty: 20 },
    ],
    totalCharge: 100,
    qtySum: 50,
  },
  {
    charge: [
      { id: "3", qty: 30 },
      { id: "4", qty: 40 },
    ],
    totalCharge: 70,
    qtySum: 100,
  },
];

const res = arr
  .map(({ charge, totalCharge, qtySum }) =>
    charge.map(({ id, qty, stySum }) => ({
      id,
      calcQty: (totalCharge * qty) / qtySum,
    }))
  )
  .flat();

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) twice to get the math action done.

Try like below.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    charge: [
      { id: "1", qty: 10 },
      { id: "2", qty: 20 },
    ],
    totalCharge: 100,
    qtySum: 50,
  },
  {
    charge: [
      { id: "3", qty: 30 },
      { id: "4", qty: 40 },
    ],
    totalCharge: 70,
    qtySum: 100,
  },
];

const output = [];

arr.forEach(({ charge, totalCharge, qtySum }) => {
  charge.forEach(({ id, qty }) => {
    output.push({ id, calcQty: (qty * totalCharge) / qtySum });
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map nested arrays and get a flat result.

```js
const
    array = [{ charge: [{ id: '1', qty: 10 }, { id: '2', qty: 20 }], totalCharge: 100, qtySum: 50 }, { charge: [{ id: '3', qty: 30 }, { id: '4', qty: 40 }], totalCharge: 70, qtySum: 100 }],
    result = array.flatMap(({ charge, totalCharge, qtySum }) =>
        charge.map(({ id, qty }) => ({
            id,
            calcQty: qty * totalCharge / qtySum
        }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```